# Azure function sendgrid email not being received

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, sendgrid

I have an Azure Function that serves as a contact form for a website, my function seems to work returning 200 OK, but I am not receiving the email.

It uses the Azure sendgrid binding, send grid shows no activity and the target mailbox does not receive anything.

Assuming all my API keys are correct here is the function bellow

```
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    if (req.body.email) {
        var message = {
            from: {
                email: req.body.email
            },
            subject: "Contact form submission from: " + req.body.name,
            content: [{
                type: 'text/plain',
                value: req.body.message
            }]
        };

        context.done(null, message);

        return {
            res: {
                status: 200
            },
            message: message
        };
    } else {
        return {
            res: {
                status: 400
            }
        };
    }
};
```

my function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "message",
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "direction": "out",
      "apiKey" : "ASSUME_THIS_IS_CORRECT",
      "to": "$SomeoneTo@somewhere.tld",
      "from": "$someoneFrom@somewhere.tld",
      "subject": "Someone Mailed Ya!"
  }
  ]
}
```

my host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
      "sendGrid": {
          "from": "Full Name <$SomeoneFrom@somwhere.tld>"
      }
  }
}
```

I gave the api key full access key so not too sure what's up with this?

Comment: add some logging and see if it actually goes to your sendemail branch

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that? My understanding is that the return value is passed to the sendGrid binding?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the same code i have tried:

```
module.exports = function (context, order) {    
    context.log(order);
    var message = {
         "personalizations": [ { "to": [ { "email": "testto@gmail.com" } ] } ],
        from: { email: "testfrom@gmail.com" },        
        subject: "Azure news",
        content: [{
            type: 'text/plain',
            value: order
        }]
    };

    context.done(null, {message});
};
```

and the binding was:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "name": "order",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "samples-orders"
    },
    {
      "type": "sendGrid",
      "name": "message",
      "direction": "out",
      "apiKey": "mysendgridkey",
      "from": "testfrom@gmail.com",
      "to": "testto@gmail.com"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

in the Gmail, i allowed access to less secure apps

[image]

and it worked. Try and see if it works.

Comment: I'm not using google I'm using outlook? does the from try use some smtp ? I was assuming it just sent as from similar to a sendmail from which is not actually sent from that user